# how to pass args to a signal

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email)          
user.password=password1
#user.set_password(password1)
user.save()
```

models.py:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #here i want user password unencrypted where I pass that parameter to this
      signal

        post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sending signals
>
> There are two ways to send send signals in Django.

```
Signal.send(sender, **kwargs)

Signal.send_robust(sender, **kwargs)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#sending-signals

In your case, you may do something like this

```
# not the real word code.
Signal.send(User, raw_password="xxx")

# raw password stays in **kwargs

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

if created:
      //here i want user password unencrypted where I pass that parameter to this
      raw_pass = kwargs.get('raw_password')
```

Comment: Note that django sender always is class, not instance. Acctually You can pass anything as sender, but better to do this in the same way as django itself.